# Regex to replace all numbers and special chars with empty spaces?

Tags: java, regex

How can I replace all numbers and special chars with empty spaces in a string (using Java)?

Comment: did you tried on your own, you can find many example by googling

Comment: read about regex : http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/

Comment: Try This
String str = "_dfgh/-+!@#$%^&())\";:[]{}\\ |wetyk 6_78 _dfgh";
String result = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z _]", "");

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\P{L}", " ");
```

will replace every character that's not a letter with a space.

Answer (score 5):

`myString = myString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z_]", " ");`
this will replace all charactes which are not letters and underlines

Comment: So `é` is not a letter, then?

Comment: then it will be replaced. `é` is kind of a special character. If he don't want to replace characters like this, he should include all of them into the regex because there are many many letters like this and many many special characters.

Comment: Just to clarify Tim: é is a letter (and not a special character). And its impossible to include all of them into the regex. The only solution here is to use the appropriate Unicode property like @TimPietzcker did.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by empty space?  Do you mean you want to delete those characters (replace them with nothing)?

```
String text2 = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha} ]", ""); // leaves letters and spaces.
```

If you run

```
String text = "String text2 = text.replaceAll(\"[^\\p{Alpha} ]\", \"\");";
String text2 = text.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha} ]", "");
System.out.println(text2);
```

you get

```
String text  textreplaceAllw
```

Comment: I have added an example, and fixed it.  It didn't remove letter, nor numbers, but I fixed that.