# Remove special characters and numbers from a string but ignore the white spaces between the words?

Tags: java, android

I want a java regex that could convert this simple sentence like this:

```
1) I am a (happy) person!!!
```

into

```
I am a happy person.
```

i.e. ignore all the numbers and special characters but ignore the white space between the words.

I am using this regex right now:

```
("\\P{L}", "")
```

but it is giving a output like:

```
Iamahappyperson
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to replace all numbers and special chars with empty spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564454/regex-to-replace-all-numbers-and-special-chars-with-empty-spaces)

Comment: try my answer now ( String new_string = "I am a (happy) person!!!".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]+",""); )  i forgot to include the white space

Comment: Respect for not using a-zA-Z. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/01/forget-iso-8859-1.html : Regex examples and tutorials always give you the [a-zA-Z0-9]+ regex to "validate alphanumeric input". It is built-in in many validation frameworks. And it is so utterly wrong. This is a regex that must never appear anywhere in your code, unless you have a pretty good explanation. Yet, the example is ubiquitous. Instead, the right regex is [\p{L}0-9]+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex `[^\p{Alpha} ]`

- `\p{Alpha}`   An alphabetic character:`[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}]`
- `[^\p{Alpha} ]` All character except alphabetic and space

Here is how you can use this :

```
System.out.println("1) I am a (happy) person!!!".replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha} ]", ""));
```

If you want to keep unicode alphabet character add just add `(?U)` at the start of the above regex.Here `(?U)` turn on `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag

Comment: System.out.print("1) I am a (happy) person!!!".replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha} ]", "") + ".");
  For the period.

Comment: It is worth considering that \p{Alpha} will match only ASCII letters by default (you must turn on UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag). \p{L} will always match any UTF-8 letter.

Comment: @MikhailAntonov you are right. I was editing the answer for that

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("I am a (happy) person!!!".replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]", ""));
```

prints out "I am a happy person"

Answer (score -1):

Try using this methode

```
String new_string = "I am a (happy) person!!!".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]+","");
```

The code:

```
public class HelloWorld
{  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    String new_string = "I am a (happy) person!!!".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]+","");
    System.out.print(new_string);

  }
}
```

The output: I am a happy person

Answer (score -1):

`[a-zA-Z\d\s]` if you want to keep alphanumeric and space.

`[a-zA-Z\s]` for alpha and space only.