# Regex to match numeric and special characters

Tags: java

I need regex which matches as per below values:

1. abc123   - Do not match
2. 123      - Match
3. a123bc   - Do not match
4. a#b%c    - Match
5. 13&ab12% - Match
6. আফ্রিকার  - Do not match

In short, it matches with only numeric string and any string with special character(#,&,%). Also it do not match with any other language string.

I tried this regex but it didn't work for me.

```
"^[\\d][#&%]+$"
```

Comment: Your regex reads: "Match one non-numeric character followed by any character which is not `#`, `&` or `%`, one or times". Perhaps you should review the rules of regex.

Comment: Should `#আফ্রিকার` match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below regex :

```
^((?=.*[#&%]).+|\d+)$
```

Explanation :

```
^               -> Start of the string
(?=.*[#&%]).+   -> Match at least one special character (#,&,%) from One or more character
|               -> Or Condition
\d              -> Match digit
$               -> End of the String
```

Comment: Oops. Thanks @Pshemo

Comment: If I am not mistaken `(?=.*[#&%]).+` would match same as `.*[#&%].+`. Anyway something tells me that we can't use `.*` since it would match *any* character but OP claims "it do not match with any other language string" which may suggest `\w*` instead (or something alike). But to be sure OP would need to answer if `#আফ্রিকার` should match or not.

Comment: @Pshemo When the string contain only one character which is special character, first one will not match but second one will

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Thanks for the answer. Now can I have the opposite regex? For eg. `abc123` should match but `123` shouldn't.

Comment: Use this regex : "(?U)^((?=\\p{Alnum}*\\p{Alpha})\\p{Alnum}+)$"
Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/43214777/2320144 for explanation

Comment: Thanks @AshrafulIslam for the reply. it fails for non-english language string `আফ্রিকার`. and with other special characters. Anyway I will look further. Again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
"^\\d+|(.*[#&%].*)$"
```

Comment: In Java there is not `/regex/flags` syntax so you need to remove enclosing `/`. Also you probably meant `\d` instead of `\D` since OP *wants* to accept string containing only numbers.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited my answer (I put `/.../` for a more generic answer on regex, but since this is flagged java, and not regex, it's probably better this way)